# Heroku using pip rather than pip3 in deployment

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm having an issue with deployment for a simple Django application to Heroku.

I have python 3.5.2 specified in runtime.txt so upon deployment to Heroku, it uses python 3.5.2.

When I push to my Heroku repository though, Heroku will try pip installing my dependencies and rather than using pip3. I know there is a duplicate post out there, but I didn't find that answer sufficient.

If anyone has had a similar problem, any advice would be great!

Comment: Actually the pip is the same code for both Python 2 and 3. On *some* systems where both Python 2 and 3 are installed there are the aliases: `pip2` for `python2 -m pip` , `pip3` for `python3 -m pip`, `pip` or `python -m pip` (meaning the default python which depends on the system) - in a virtualenv you always have `pip`

Comment: What makes you think this is causing a problem?

Comment: if there is a duplicate post then please add the link so that other people can find it if they want :)